# Render markdown in mu4e buffers

Tags: email, mu4e, markdown

I recently moved to mu4e for my email and it works great except that the way my university formats emails makes them look really weird in emacs (light grey background, white foreground). I was advised that pressing 'h' can toggle off html but this didn't change anything. I then used `html2text` and now I have some markdown in the email buffer, this is at least legible but not ideal. Is there any way I can render the markdown thats in the email?

Answer (score 1):

Some emails are best viewed in the browser.

`mu4e` supports  `mu4e-actions`

Add the following to your `.emacs` file:

```
(add-to-list 'mu4e-view-actions
  '("ViewInBrowser" . mu4e-action-view-in-browser) t)
```

have a read! [here is the doc](https://www.djcbsoftware.nl/code/mu/mu4e/Actions.html#Actions)

Now with <kbd>a</kbd> followed by a <kbd>V</kbd> your email opens in your favourite browser.